# Best place to submit prestashop template and modules?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have made a prestashop template and modules i want to submit it for sell. Which is the best market place to sell prestashop items?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about selling Prestashop templates

Comment: If you try to submit your module to the official prestashop validation team, you're about to get crazy. Make your own marketplace, it will be easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place is the official PrestaShop Addons Store:
http://addons.prestashop.com